# Knockout.jsについて

Tags: javascript

「Knockout.js 」はJavaScriptフレームワークの中でも古いと言われますがどの年代で主流としてシステム開発に取り入れられるようになったものなのでしょうか。またシステム開発をこれから行うときにKnockout.jsを取り入れる企業はあるのでしょうか。

Comment: knockout.jsは最新のブラウザーで動かないわけでもないし、[次期バージョン](https://github.com/knockout/tko)の開発も継続しているので好みなら採用すればいいと思いますよ

Comment: 手っ取り早くトレンドを知りたいのであればGoogle Trendで同様なものとの検索数を比較すると大体の流れがつかめると思います。
JavaScriptフレームワーク系であればこちらとか。
https://trends.google.co.jp/trends/explore?date=all&q=knockoutjs,react.js,vue.js,angular.js

Comment: Google Trendと同系統の手段としては[Stack Overflow Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=knockout.js%2Creactjs%2Cvue.js%2Cangular)も。